# If the sum of a few positive real numbers is 30 then what would be their maximum product?can it be solved from a different method?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the sum of a few positive real numbers is 30 then what would be their maximum product?

Are there any other method apart from this ?

IS this ok--Let sum of few positive no=p

We divided p into equal parts =x

- am>=gm
  $$\dfrac px\ge(product)^{1/x}$$
  $$\left(\dfrac px\right)^x\ge(products)$$
- to Maximize products we have to maximize $(\frac px)^x$
  So let $$y=\left(\dfrac px\right)^x\tag1$$
- for Maximize this differentiate with respect to x and put equal to zero   for critical points
  $$y'=\left(\dfrac px\right)^x\left(\ln\dfrac pe-1\right)=0$$
  $$\frac p{xe}=1$$
- $x=\frac pe$----- critical point for max
  Put in equation $(1)$
  $$y=(p/x)^x$$
  $$y_{max}=(p/(p/e)^p)/e$$
  $y_{max}=(e)^{p/e}$
  In this question $p=30,$
  $$y(max)=(e)^{30/e}.$$

Comment: Not quite: the maximum value is attained when $x = \frac{30}{e}$. Then you still have to determine the integer closest to that number.

Comment: @TobyMak Doesn't appear that this question is looking to find the solution across only the integers -- I'd suppose that all reals are valid.

Comment: The count of how many numbers has to be a whole number.

Comment: I suppose, as well, that you are expected to prove by induction that the maximum product occurs when all the factors are the same (i.e. your statement about splitting p into equal parts)?  That'd be a nice exercise.

Comment: If you use the fact that the maximum of $x^{1/x}$ occurs at $x=e$, then substituting $x \to \frac{30}{x}$, we get that the maximum of $(30/x)^(x/30)$ occurs at $x=\frac{30}{e}$. Since raising $x$ to the power of $30$ does not change the maximum, the function also has a maximum of $x=\frac{30}{e}$.

Comment: New approximation added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since parameter $z$ is integer, then
$$g_m = \max\limits_{z\in\mathbb N} g(z),$$
where
$$g(z)=\left(\dfrac{30}z\right)^z.$$

Then 
$$g_m = g(z_m),\tag1$$ where
$$\left(\dfrac{30}{z+1}\right)^{z+1}\le\left(\dfrac{30}z\right)^z,$$
$$\dfrac{(z+1)^{z+1}}{z^z} \ge 30.\tag2$$

Since
$$\dfrac{11^{11}}{10^{10}}\approx28.5 <30,\quad \dfrac{12^{12}}{11^{11}}\approx 31.25 \ge 30,$$
then $z=11.\tag3$

Approximation
$$\left(\dfrac{z+1}z\right)^z\approx e$$
leads to the result
$$z = \left\lfloor \dfrac p{e_\mathstrut}\right\rfloor = 11.\tag4$$

More accurate approximation
$$\left(\dfrac{z+1}z\right)^{z+\frac12}\approx e$$

leads to the equation
$$e^2z^2+e^2z-p^2=0,$$
with the result
$$z = \left\lceil \dfrac{\sqrt{4p^2+e^2}-e_\mathstrut}{2e}\right\rceil = 11.\tag5$$

The product is
$$\left(\dfrac{30}z\right)^z\approx 62089.\tag6$$

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to split $p = 30$ into $30/e \approx 11.036$ groups of size $e$, unless $p$ is a multiple of $e$. Instead, you would need to use an integer amount of groups. You would need to test the $11$ group case and the $12$ group case (if $p = 30$) and figure out what the higher $y$ value would be.

Let's assume that you could somehow have $30/e$ groups. You made an error when you plugged your critical point into the original equation. You got $y=\frac{p/(p/e)^p}{e}$ when it should have been $$\left(\frac{p}{x} \right)^x = \left(\frac{p}{\frac{p}{e}}\right)^{p/e} = e^{p/e}$$

Comment: so what's d answer after I rectify my error ?